# Programmatically enable Auto-approval for permission requests on community site collection

Tags: 2013, development, visual-studio, site-collection

I've done some searching and cannot find a solution anywhere.
I'm creating community site collections via event receiver. I need to enable "Auto-approval for permission requests" on each site collection upon creation.
I know that in the front end you go to "Site Settings -> Community Settings" and enable it there manually. I need to do this via code.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened the page "CommunitySettings.aspx" I saw in which object references
Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal -> CommunitySettingsPage with Reflector and then I saw the internal code.

See and use it :)

```
using (SPWeb resource_0 = resource_1.OpenWeb(web.ID))
      {
        resource_0.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
        resource_0.AllProperties[(object) CommunitiesConstants.CommunityEstablishedDateKey] = (object) resource_0.RegionalSettings.TimeZone.LocalTimeToUTC(ctrl.SelectedDate);
        if (resource_0.IsRootWeb && this.CheckEnableAutoApproval.Enabled)
          resource_0.AllProperties[(object) CommunitiesConstants.CommunityEnableAutoApprovalKey] = (object) this.CheckEnableAutoApproval.Checked.ToString();
        if (resource_0.Features[CommunitiesConstants.AbuseReportsList_FeatureId] != null && this.CheckEnableReportAbuse.Checked != CommunityUtils.IsReportAbuseEnabled(resource_0))
        {
          resource_0.AllProperties[(object) CommunitiesConstants.CommunityEnableReportAbuseKey] = (object) this.CheckEnableReportAbuse.Checked.ToString();
          FunctionalityEnablers.EnableDisableAbuseReports(resource_0, this.CheckEnableReportAbuse.Checked);
        }
        resource_0.Update();
      }
```

Look this:

```
resource_0.AllProperties[(object) CommunitiesConstants.CommunityEnableAutoApprovalKey] = (object) this.CheckEnableAutoApproval.Checked.ToString();
```

Comment: Enjoy! And let me know ;)

Comment: Your suggestion worked! :) had to make a few tweaks. Thanks alot